# setting opacity to all <td> except a child in the last <td>

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
<tbody id="items">
   <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item 4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item 5</td></tr>
   <tr><td><a>1</a>
           <a>2</a>
           <a class="a3">3</a>
  </td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to set the opacity to 0.5 except the third anchor tag in the last `<td>`. How to set?

Comment: use the class of that anchor `$('.a3')......`

Comment: you want to use jquery or just html & css for this?

Comment: i want to use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var atd = $('.a3').closest('td')
$("td").not(atd).addClass('opacity')//add class here
```

You can add a class with the specific css

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahd5nLo3/)

Set opacity to child of td except class a3

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahd5nLo3/1/)

Use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

To find match then add the class

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahd5nLo3/2/)

```js
var atd = $('.a3')
$("td").each(function(index) {
console.log($(this).find('a').length)
  if ($(this).find('a').length > 0) {
    $(this).children().not(atd).addClass('opacity') //add class here
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('opacity') //add class here
  }
})
```

```css
.opacity {
  color: red;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a class="a3">3</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: i want to set the opacity as 0.5 except the last <a> tag in the last <td>

Comment: you mean all except the last a ?sorry misunderstand but same step just change the selector give me a minute

Comment: @kalles clarification you want td to have opacity .5 or just children?

Comment: sorry i can't understand.

Comment: @kalles which element do you want to have opacity the descendant of td except the one with class a3 or all as well as the td itself?

Comment: i want the opacity except the one with class a3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109009/discussion-between-guradio-and-kalles).

Comment: @kalles check the last demo or snippet this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

If the opacity of a `td` is 0.5, you can't "undo" that in a child component (give it an opacity of 1 again).

You can also not select "`td` that doesn't contain `a`" in CSS.

What I would do is to wrap the contents of the cells in a `<span>`, and do the following:

```
td span, td a {opacity: 0.5;}
.a3 {opacity: 0.1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well may be a little lengthy but a great css only solution

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a class="a3">3</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr td,
tr:last-child td a {
  opacity: .5
}

tr:last-child td,
tr:last-child td a.a3 {
  opacity: 1
}
```

> Set last child opacity to 1 and opacity of `<a>` in last list to 0.5 but not for the last `<a>`

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/4p3dfqye/

Comment: i need to use this in jquery